# Find the sum of weights of edges between every pair of nodes in a weighted tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, c++14, c++17

I need to find an efficient way to find the sum of values of all simple paths in a weighted tree. The value of a simple path is defined as the sum of weights of all edges in the given simple path.

This is my try, but it is not working. Please tell the correct approach.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, ll> pil;
const int MAXN = 1e5;
int n, color[MAXN + 2];
vector<pil> adj[MAXN + 2];
ll sum1, cnt1[MAXN + 2], cnt[MAXN + 2], res;

void visit(int u, int p)
{
    cnt[u] = 1;

    cnt1[u] = color[u];

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) adj[u].size(); ++i)
    {
        int v = adj[u][i].first;
        ll w = adj[u][i].second;

        if (v == p)
            continue;

        visit(v, u);
        ll tmp = cnt1[v] * (n - sum1 - cnt[v] + cnt1[v]);
        tmp += (cnt[v] - cnt1[v]) * (sum1 - cnt1[v]);
        res += tmp * w;

        cnt[u] += cnt[v];
        cnt1[u] += cnt1[v];
    }
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", color + i);
        sum1 += color[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1, u, v; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %lld", &u, &v, &res);
        adj[u].push_back(pil(v, res));
        adj[v].push_back(pil(u, res));
    }

    res = 0;

    visit(1, -1);
    printf("%lld\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef long long ll;` translates into English as "Let's make my code harder to read before I ask people for help." You'll find this doesn't work all that well.

Comment: This article may help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-path-between-any-two-nodes-in-a-binary-tree/

Answer (score 1):

Below is Simple implementation of what @Arjun Singh explained.

```
int64_t ans = 0;

int dfs(int node, int parent) {
    int cur_subtree_size = 1;
    for(int child : adj[node]) {
        if(parent != child) {
            int child_subtree_size = dfs(child, node);
            int64_t contribution_of_cur_edge = child_subtree_size * (N - child_subtree_size) * weight[{node, child}];
            ans += contribution_of_cur_edge;
            cur_subtree_size += child_subtree_size;
        }
    }
    return cur_subtree_size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the contribution of each edge in the final answer. Let's say an edge connects two components component1 ---- component2. Then the contribution of this edge in final answer will be -
Vertices(component1) * Vertices(component2)*edge_weight.

The no. of vertices in each component can be found easily running a dfs and calculating the number of vertices in the subtree of each vertex. Let an edge connect vertex u and v. u is the parent of v. Then, 
Vertices(v) = Number of vertices in the subtree of v = Vertices(component1)
Vertices(component2) = n - Vertices(v)

You can precalculate this subtree array. So final time complexity will be O(n).